# strange event/problem with Internet Explorer 8 and Default Mail Client Is Not Properly Installed 

Tags: networking, router, internet, email-client

I have a really strange problem.

My Network (A)
Other Network (B)

1 - When reinstalling XP or Windows 7, Internet Explorer 8 gives a message like: **Default Mail Client Is Not Properly Installed** network (A)

2 - When connecting this computer to an other provider network (B), this problem does not exist.

3 - When connecting a totally other computer to my providers network (A), the same message appears.

It looks like something in the network/modem/router triggers this event.

Does anyone see any light in the end of the tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

Check first this article from
[Vista could not perform this operation because the default mail client is not properly installed](http://www.computer-aid.com.au/blog/2009/01/31/vista-could-not-perform-this-operation-because-the-default-mail-client-is-not-properly-installed/) :

> Customer recently bought a Vista PC.
>
> After a few weeks he started getting a
>   strange error message:
>
> `Could not perform this operation because the default mail client is not properly installed.`
>
> This would happen whenever he would
>   click on a mail link within internet
>   explorer.
>
> It didn’t take long for me to realise
>   that there was something wrong with
>   mailto: links on any web page (and
>   also any mailto: link within html
>   emails.
>
> I’m sure there is a setting (or a
>   registry entry), to fix up the mailto:
>   association.
>
> I tried the following steps until it
>   started to work:
>
> 1. Start -> Default Programs -> Set Program access and computer defaults -> Custom -> default email program (you need to scroll down for this) -> set registry values to default.
> 2. Control Panel -> Default Programs -> set your default programs -> select windows mail (or your normal email client) -> Choose defaults for this program -> make sure all boxes are ticked (eg .eml, mailto:, email link)
> 3. Control Panel -> internet options -> Advanced -> Reset